# Yii2 gridview search is not working for Date field

Tags: search, yii2

In my project there is a Yii2 gridview. I have a **contacts** table and **modified** is the column in it which is date field when I search for a date in that column It gives error

```
Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'modified' in where clause is ambiguous
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `contacts` LEFT JOIN `companies` ON `contacts`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` INNER JOIN `countries` ON `contacts`.`country` = `countries`.`country_code` WHERE (`modified`='2017') AND (`modified` LIKE '%2017%')
```

If I replace the code from

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
            ...
            'modified' => $this->modified,
            ...
        ]);
```

to this code

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
            ...
            'contacts.modified' => $this->modified,
            ...
        ]);
```

If I change the code as given above,It neither gives error nor the result..
I cant understand where I am going wrong?

Comment: you were searching date against year. add your table data and how you use filter.

Comment: I have tried to search as 2017-10-12 ,2017, 2017 Dec and all the possibilities

Comment: Table data is in this format " 2017-09-26 13:22:47"

Comment: what is `$this->modified` value?

Comment: modified is a column name .. and $this->modified ,is in gii generated modelSearch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'DATE_FORMAT(contacts.modified, "%Y-%m-%d")' => \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($this->modified, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
]);
```

Refer [asDate()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asDate()-detail)

Comment: Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"%Y-%m-%d)='2017-09-26')' at line 1
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `contacts` LEFT JOIN `companies` ON `contacts`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` INNER JOIN `countries` ON `contacts`.`country` = `countries`.`country_code` WHERE (`modified`='2017-09-26') AND (DATE_FORMAT(contacts.modified, "%Y-%m-%d)='2017-09-26')

Comment: Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'modified' in where clause is ambiguous
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `contacts` LEFT JOIN `companies` ON `contacts`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` INNER JOIN `countries` ON `contacts`.`country` = `countries`.`country_code` WHERE (`modified`='2017-09-26') AND (DATE_FORMAT(contacts.modified, "%Y-%m-%d")='2017-09-26')

Comment: you compare two time `modified`. please remove `'modified' => $this->modified`.

Comment: now not showing error nor result.:(  dont know whats going wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160919/discussion-between-goli-and-vishub).

Comment: heyyy Its working.. but how to use.. $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'contacts.modified', $endDate, $today]);... In above format

Comment: If I search for blank It shows no result ..Why so??.. for other column if I search for blank it shows all entries in a table